# Pass values from API to triggered send

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, triggered-send

I have created a SOAP api post in postman that is supposed to pass the subscriberkey and a custom field (LoyaltyID) but the custom field doesn't look to be coming through.

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
        <fueloauth>token</fueloauth>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Options/>
            <Objects xsi:type="TriggeredSend">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                <TriggeredSendDefinition>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <CustomerKey>Loyalty_Welcome_NU_DE</CustomerKey>
                </TriggeredSendDefinition>
                <Subscribers>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <EmailAddress>parvez.halim+loyaltytest1@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
                    <SubscriberKey>0030N00xxxxxxx</SubscriberKey>
                    <LoyaltyID>a0X0N00xxxxxxxxx</LoyaltyID>
                </Subscribers>
            </Objects>
        </CreateRequest>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

and here is the ampscript on the triggered send email:

```
<!--%%[
VAR @futureDate, @today, @timestamp, @formattedDate, @url_yes, @RecordId, @subId, @subLanguage, @subscription, @subscriptionRow, @rowCount, @result, @loyalty

SET @today = Now(1) 
SET @timestamp = Format(@today, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
SET @futureDate = DateAdd(@today, 30, 'D')
SET @formattedDate = Format(@futureDate,'yyyy-MM-dd')

SET @RecordId = AttributeValue('SubscriberKey')
SET @loyalty = AttributeValue('LoyaltyID')

SET @subscription = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('MAG_Subscription__c','Subscription_ID__c, MAG_Language__c', 'MAG_Contact__c', '=', @RecordId)
SET @rowCount = rowCount(@subscription)

IF @rowCount > 0 THEN

    SET @subscriptionRow = Row(@subscription, @rowCount)
    SET @subId = FIELD(@subscriptionRow, 'Subscription_ID__c')
    SET @sublanguage = FIELD(@subscriptionRow, 'MAG_Language__c')

ENDIF

UpdateDE('Loyalty Welcome DE',1,'SubscriberKey',@RecordId,'SubscriptionID',@subId, LoyaltyID, @loyalty)

SET @url_yes = Concat('https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/g3eu24p0efj?sk=',@subId,'&ln=',@subLanguage,'&expiry=',@formattedDate)

SET @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('MAG_Subscription__c',@subId,'MAG_Status__c','Pending Verification')

SET @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('MAG_Subscription__c',@subId,'MAG_VerifiedRequestDate__c', @timestamp)

]%%
```

I'm thinking that i cannot just add values within the  tags. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to insert Custom Field value within Attributes which will be within `<Subscribers>` Tag.

```
<Subscribers>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <EmailAddress>parvez.halim+loyaltytest1@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
                    <Attributes>
                          <Name>LoyaltyID</Name>                                                
                          <Value>a0X0N00xxxxxxxxx</Value>
                    </Attributes>
</Subscribers>
```